# Change background-color of mouse-over row

Tags: html, css, background-color, mouseover

Once we mouse-over on "currency", we can see drop down as below:

[image]

what I need is once we mouse-over on particular currency[ row], it should show different background color like below.

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
.menuBackground {
    background: brown;
    text-align: center;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    color: #FFF;
}
.dropDownMenu,
.dropDownMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu li {
    position: relative;
}
.dropDownMenu a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropDownMenu a:first-child { 
color: #000; 
}
.dropDownMenu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: -4px; /* solve the 4 pixels spacing between list-items */
}
.dropDownMenu > li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.dropDownMenu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
.dropDownMenu > li > ul {
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
</style>
```

How?

Comment: use style on hover and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its good to add colors on anchor tag not to `li` because you have already styled color on anchor, So just add hover css on anchor you will see what you want.

```
.dropDownMenu li a:hover {
   background: #fff; /*Your color*/
   color: #000; /*Your color*/
}
```

Comment: Its good you give the answer but it will be great if you will add little bit explanation too.

Comment: can you please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269248/display-background-color-for-the-page-align-texts-at-center

Answer (score 1):

Try this, on particular row hover effect as below:

And change background-color for currency li hover green to white.

```
.dropDownMenu > li > ul {
  background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
  display: block !important;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  top: 100%;
  width: 240px;
  z-index: 999999;
}

ul.dropDownMenu li ul li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Why you are making small things into complex code?? and still you are not mentioning the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do is give style on ul li then consider as parent > child. So what you need is to change the background color and color on hover of li.

```
.dropDownMenu a:hover {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
}
```

What i did is, i give css on hover of your dropdown menu. You can do it for more child according to > selector.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following css will make like your expected output.

```
#select-language ul li:hover
{
  background-color:white
}
```